# yii-user-management Yumuser.php get() on a non-object yum_user_relations

Tags: yii

I have just installed the yii-user-management module but when I try to access it via browser I get

Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in ..../modules/user/models/YumUser.php on line 368

```
$relations = Yii::app()->cache->get('yum_user_relations');
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the yii-user-management module requires a [`cache`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#cache-detail) component for it to work. So in your application config add the cache component as

```
'cache'=>array(
    'class'=>'CDummyCache',
),
```

Here we are using [`CDummyCache`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDummyCache) copmponent which is, as its name says, acts as a dummy. You can replace it by any other cache components as described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dInGd0nG. Your answer works for me too. Just would want to remind people to follow his link. In the link, you will see the configure statement shall be added in

```
'components'=>array(
       ......
        'cache'=>array(
            'class'=>'CDummyCache',
        ),
)
```